# Updating Rstudio in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: rstudio

I have downloaded a newer version of Rstudio from the official website but don't know how to update it. Please help!

Answer (score 6):

Easy way via GUI:

1. See that an update is available (in RStudio by selecting *Help* then *Check for updates*, same as karel's answer).
2. You then navigate to https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/ and under *Installers for Supported Platforms* go to the one for your OS (mine is same as question, Ubuntu 16.04 +) and click on it.
3. When faced with the *open* or *download* option, select *open with the Software Installer* (actually the default option).
4. The file will open with the 'Ubuntu Software' program and will prompt you to install R-studio via a blue button. Click that blue button marked *install*.

Next time you open R-Studio it will be the most up to date version.

Answer (score 4):

You can check for new versions of RStudio from within RStudio by going to the *Help* menu and clicking *Check for Updates*.

To check for package updates select *Tools* -> *Check for Package Updates*. You can also check for package updates another way by selecting **Packages** tab -> click *Update*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Installer could not open the file. I just used the command line:

```
cd Downloads
sudo gdebi rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb
```

(or whatever is your version)